# MS Virtual PC and licensing question

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, license

I already have a license for Windows XP and I have installed MS Virtual PC. Now I would like to install same Windows XP on virtual session. Does this violate licensing agreement? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the licence will not be valid if you are using a standard OEM, retail or upgrade package - You will need a new licence for use within the virtual machine.

If this is for testing and or development, you may be able to take a look at [various VHD programs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb738372.aspx) that Microsoft offer and find one that matches your needs. You simply download a few files and are ready to go.

Comment: +1 nice vhd list.  I thought MS had stopped providing these.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a site license key that allows you to install multiple copies using the same key, you have to buy a new license for each Windows virtual machine (VM) you want to run Windows XP on.  Your license probably includes something similar to:

> "You may install, use, access, display and run one copy of the Software on a
>   single computer, such as a workstation, terminal or other device
>   ("Workstation Computer")."

From the Windows XP SP2 Pro EULA.

References:

1. [Windows XP & VM's](http://wskills.blogspot.com/2006/12/windows-xp-activation-and-virtual.html)
2. [Windows VM, XP Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Windows_XP_Mode)
3. [Microsoft Volume Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/default.aspx)